# How to retrieve values from the hash?

Tags: perl, hash

How to retrieve value of `d` in this hash:

```
'a' => {    
        'b' => {    
        'c' => {    
                'd' => 'e'   
       }
```

Comment: Am getting Can't use string ("XXXX") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at

Comment: What did you try to get that error?

Comment: `$foo{'a'}{'c'}{'d'}`?

Comment: @KarthikeyanM: You should really show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

You've a 3 level deep hash - assuming you've a typo and your hash looks like:

```
my %hash = (
    'a' => {
        'b' => {},
        'c' => { 'd' => 'e' }
    }
    );

print $hash{a}{c}{d};
```

If that bracket is at the end though:

```
my %hash = ( 'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => { 'd' => 'e' } } } );

print $hash{a}{b}{c}{d};
```

Comment: Commonly known as a "hohoho" ;)

Comment: Having said that - part of this depends where the missing brackets go.

Comment: You probably didn't mean to write `$a` there.

Comment: No, amended. and added some examples of hash declaration to clarify.

Comment: @TLP it's not time for the hats yet... :)

Comment: You could add the hashref case, too, it's not clear from the question what the input really is.